# Using an alias in a window function in a query in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I am using PostgreSQL version 9.1 and looking at the [Postgres docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html), I know it is possible to do the following:

```
SELECT salary, sum(salary) OVER (ORDER BY salary) FROM empsalary;
```

and this works for my queries.

Now I need to be able to specify an alias instead of a column name in the `OVER (ORDER BY ...)` ?

I have tried this:

**EDIT:** I previously forgot to add the `rank()` to this query:

```
SELECT salary, <complex expression> as result, rank() OVER (ORDER BY result) FROM empsalary;
```

and I am getting an error saying that `column "result" does not exist.`

Is it possible to specify an alias instead of a column name here? Am I missing some special syntax?

**EDIT:**

I am using Hibernate, with some native SQL for the window function. The full SQL that is generated and executed is below:

```
select 
       rank() OVER (ORDER BY deltahdlcOverruns DESC) as rank, 

       this_.deviceNo as y1_, 

       (SELECT _dev_.hdlcOverruns FROM abstractperformancestatistic _abs_ 
        INNER JOIN enddevicestatistic _dev_ ON _dev_.id = _abs_.id 
        INNER JOIN linkstatistic _link_ ON _link_.id = _dev_.linkStatistic_id 
        INNER JOIN iptstatistic _ipt_ ON _ipt_.id = _link_.iptStat_id 
        WHERE this_.deviceNo=_dev_.deviceNo AND _abs_.dateTime <= '3910-06-07 00:00:00.0'
        ORDER BY _abs_.dateTime DESC LIMIT 1
       ) 
       - 
       (SELECT _dev_.hdlcOverruns FROM abstractperformancestatistic _abs_ 
        INNER JOIN enddevicestatistic _dev_ ON _dev_.id = _abs_.id 
        INNER JOIN linkstatistic _link_ ON _link_.id = _dev_.linkStatistic_id 
        INNER JOIN iptstatistic _ipt_ ON _ipt_.id = _link_.iptStat_id 
        WHERE this_.deviceNo=_dev_.deviceNo AND _abs_.dateTime >= '3870-06-01 00:00:00.0' 
        ORDER BY _abs_.dateTime LIMIT 1
       ) 
       AS deltahdlcOverruns from EndDeviceStatistic this_ 

       inner join AbstractPerformanceStatistic this_1_ on this_.id=this_1_.id 
       inner join AbstractEntity this_2_ on this_.id=this_2_.id 
       left outer join RawEndDeviceStatistic this_3_ on this_.id=this_3_.id 
       left outer join LinkStatistic l2_ on this_.linkStatistic_id=l2_.id 
       left outer join AbstractPerformanceStatistic l2_1_ on l2_.id=l2_1_.id 
       left outer join AbstractEntity l2_2_ on l2_.id=l2_2_.id 
       left outer join RawLinkStatistic l2_3_ on l2_.id=l2_3_.id 
       left outer join IPTStatistic i1_ on l2_.iptStat_id=i1_.id 
       left outer join AbstractPerformanceStatistic i1_1_ on i1_.id=i1_1_.id 
       left outer join AbstractEntity i1_2_ on i1_.id=i1_2_.id 
       left outer join RawIPTStatistic i1_3_ on i1_.id=i1_3_.id 

       where this_1_.dateTime between ? and ? 

       group by this_.deviceNo limit ?
```

Comment: Rather than assign an alias to the result of the window function, what I'm attempting to do is to calculate a rank() over an alias. I missed out the rank in the original query I posted, I have corrected it now!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Place the alias **behind** the `OVER` clause:

```
SELECT salary
     , sum(salary) OVER (ORDER BY salary) AS my_alias
FROM   empsalary;
```

#### Edit after question update

You cannot reference a column alias (an "output column") at the same level of a `SELECT`. You need a subselect or a [CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) for this. Like:

```
SELECT id, result, rank() OVER (ORDER BY result) AS rnk
FROM  (
    SELECT id, <complex expression> AS result
    FROM   tbl
    WHERE  <some condition>
    GROUP  BY id
    ) sub;
```

For your query:

```
SELECT rank() OVER (ORDER BY deltahdlcOverruns) AS rnk
     , y1_
     , deltahdlcOverruns
FROM  (
    SELECT this_.deviceNo as y1_
        ,  (SELECT _dev_.hdlcOverruns FROM abstractperformancestatistic _abs_ 
            JOIN   enddevicestatistic _dev_ USING (id)
            JOIN   linkstatistic _link_ ON _link_.id = _dev_.linkStatistic_id 
            JOIN   iptstatistic _ipt_ ON _ipt_.id = _link_.iptStat_id 
            WHERE  this_.deviceNo=_dev_.deviceNo
            AND    _abs_.dateTime <= '3910-06-07 00:00:00.0'
            ORDER  BY _abs_.dateTime DESC
            LIMIT  1
           ) 
           - 
           (SELECT _dev_.hdlcOverruns FROM abstractperformancestatistic _abs_ 
            JOIN   enddevicestatistic _dev_ USING (id)
            JOIN   linkstatistic _link_ ON _link_.id = _dev_.linkStatistic_id 
            JOIN   iptstatistic _ipt_ ON _ipt_.id = _link_.iptStat_id 
            WHERE  this_.deviceNo=_dev_.deviceNo
            AND    _abs_.dateTime >= '3870-06-01 00:00:00.0' 
            ORDER  BY _abs_.dateTime
            LIMIT  1
           ) AS deltahdlcOverruns
    FROM   EndDeviceStatistic this_ 
    JOIN   AbstractPerformanceStatistic this_1_ USING (id)
    JOIN   AbstractEntity this_2_ USING (id)
    LEFT   JOIN RawEndDeviceStatistic this_3_ USING (id)
    LEFT   JOIN LinkStatistic l2_ ON this_.linkStatistic_id = l2_.id 
    LEFT   JOIN AbstractPerformanceStatistic l2_1_ ON l2_.id = l2_1_.id 
    LEFT   JOIN AbstractEntity l2_2_ ON l2_.id = l2_2_.id 
    LEFT   JOIN RawLinkStatistic l2_3_ ON l2_.id = l2_3_.id 
    LEFT   JOIN IPTStatistic i1_ ON l2_.iptStat_id = i1_.id 
    LEFT   JOIN AbstractPerformanceStatistic i1_1_ ON i1_.id = i1_1_.id 
    LEFT   JOIN AbstractEntity i1_2_ ON i1_.id = i1_2_.id 
    LEFT   JOIN RawIPTStatistic i1_3_ ON i1_.id = i1_3_.id 
    WHERE  this_1_.dateTime between ? and ? 
    GROUP  BY this_.deviceNo
    LIMIT  ?
) x;
```

I made a few *additional syntax simplifications*.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have posted the full SQL query from the log, hopefully that should show up the problem.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I will need to do, unfortunately it is tricky doing subselects in Hibernate, but that is my next problem to solve!

Answer (score 7):

wrap the windowing in a surrounding query:

```
SELECT salary, result OVER (ORDER BY result)
FROM (SELECT salary, (...expression...) AS result
      FROM empsalary
     ) x
```

Comment: Yes, the subselect is what I need to do. Erwin came up with a similar solution in his answer - if I could accept both answers I would! +1